# How to apply the reduce method for objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, reduce

I was reading about the reduce method for arrays in JavaScript and I have found the following example on MDN web docs:

```js
var initialValue = 0;
var sum = [{x: 1}, {x:2}, {x:3}].reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.x
    ,initialValue
);

console.log(sum) // logs 6
```

When I ran this I didn't get as a result "6", but "[object Object]710"

But when I ran it on Stackoverflow snippet I got "6".

What's wrong?

Comment: `When I ran this` I guess your code is different from the code posted here, else your result would've been the same...

Comment: Perhaps you should post code that demonstrates **your problem**, not code that runs correctly

Comment: I ran this code in browser console and got `6`. You are doing  something wrong which only you can figure out :)

Comment: Ohh you guys are right, my mistake! I did not add the initial value in my code. Here's my code:

var sum = [{x: 1}, {x:2}, {x:3}].reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
    return accumulator + currentValue.x;
})

console.log(sum)

But when it's not an objects array, it's possible to not put the initial value. So it's a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

When the initial value isn’t supplied, the first iteration uses the 0th element as `accumulator` and the 1st element as `currentValue`. This would work for summing an array of numbers, and a few other useful cases.

```
var reducer = ( acc, val ) => {
    console.log( acc, val );
    return acc + val;
})

[ 1, 2, 3 ].reduce( reducer )
-> 1, 2
-> 3, 3

[ 1, 2, 3 ].reduce( reducer, 0 )
-> 0, 1
-> 1, 2
-> 3, 3
```

To put it another way, leaving out the initial value in your case is like doing:

```
[{x: 2}, {x: 3}].reduce( ( acc, val ) => acc + val.x, {x: 1} );
```

Therefore the first iteration evaluates to `{x: 1} + 2`.

`reduce` with an empty array and no initial value will error, so it’s good practice to always supply it.

Comment: Why does [1, 2, 3].reduce(reducer) returns 6 while lets say: [{x:1}, {x:2}, {x:3}].reduce(reducer)  with reducer = (acc, val) => acc + val.x 
returns [object Object]23? I mean in the first case we don't need an initial value but in the second we need one to get 6 as a result?

Comment: Edited with clarification

Comment: Oh thank you! This answers perfectly my question. As you recommend I will always supply the initial value :)